# How much salt should I put in a vegetable stew?

Tags: salt, vegan, stews

I'm making a vegan vegetables soup (i.e no powders or prepared stock - just fresh vegetables and fresh spices), and I'm not sure how much salt to put in to just bring out the flavor without getting the stew actually salty.

Any rule of thumb that I can use? I heard that potatoes absorb saltiness so you have to add extra salt when cooking with potatoes.

Answer (score 6):

Salt is very much an individual thing. Luckily, you can always add more if needed.

The only rule of thumb I can think of is to add a little, taste, and see if it needs more.

I would also suggest sweating the vegetables before adding water, with some salt on them. Brings out the flavours better, thus needing less salt overall for flavour.

Comment: It's always a good idea to salt at the beginning and end of cooking. +1